# SSD for apps and RAID-0 for data?

Tags: ssd, raid-0

I am building a new PC.  I am going to be using a 64gb OCZ Vertex SSD for Windows and other programs.  I then will have regular drives for my data.  I am thinking maybe I should run 2 hard dives in RAID-0 for my data storage, it will not matter if there is drive failure to much as I will have backups frequently of this stuff.  I am just curious will I need any extra hardware to do this RAID-0 on my extra drives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> will I need any extra hardware to do
>   this RAID-0 on my extra drives?

That depends entirely on your motherboard/controller and whether it supports RAID or not. If it doesn't, you can always use software RAID.

However, RAID-0 just for storage doesn't really make sense; I'd rather RAID 2 OCZ Vertex and double the speed (well, almost).

[image]

Comment: Raid-0 (spanning) makes sense if you need to have bigger partitions than individual disks. But it is more vulnerable (if any disk fails, all the data is lost).

Answer (score 2):

That's a pretty cost-effective solution for speed.  2 RAID0 SSD's would set you back a pretty penny.  2 RAID0 7200RPM drives would give you a nice IO boost for less $$.

I think Windows 7 will do RAID0 (striping) itself, so as long as it can see the drives, you're OK.  Also, most major motherboards these days support some sort of RAID capability on their SATA controllers, so that could also be an option.  If you get a budget mobo, go with Windows striping.  If you get a decent mobo, use the built-in RAID.

I know you said you'd be backing up the data RAID0 frequently, but I hope frequently means hourly because that's the only way I'd use RAID0 for data storage.